# Numerical information about variables in prostate cancer data

Tags: data, prostate

This question seems to be weird at first glance but I think this is the appropriate place to ask.

I'm studying Prostate data by Stamey et. al., (1989), data to examine the correlation between the level of prostate-specific antigen and a number of clinical measures in men who were about to receive a radical prostatectomy.

The variables:

```
lcavol: log cancer volume

lweight: log prostate weight

age: in years

lbph: log of the amount of benign prostatic hyperplasia

svi: seminal vesicle invasion

lcp: log of capsular penetration

gleason: a numeric vector

pgg45: percent of Gleason score 4 or 5

lpsa: response
```

I wonder if there is a **numerical medical information** about these variables. For example, “Is there a numerical relationship between `log cancer volume` and `log prostate weight`?”,

OR, for instance, Can someone say something like “We expect that `seminal vesicle invasion` is double amount of `log prostate weight`”?

**EDIT**:

For additional information about publications:

(1) [Prostate specific antigen in the diagnosis and treatment of adenocarcinoma of the prostate. II. Radical prostatectomy treated patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2468795)

(2) [Regression shrinkage and selection via the lasso](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf)

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify this further. An actual link to the paper(s) you reference would be helpful for starters.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the post according to your advice.